# measuring network throughput with netperf

Tags: networking, linux-networking, performance-tuning, benchmark

I'm doing benchmark test of Linux server using netperf. According to 
information at [networksecuritytoolkit](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/LAN_Ethernet_Maximum_Rates,_Generation,_Capturing_%26_Monitoring#Gigabit_Ethernet_Using_UDP) the theoretical max throughput rate for 1514-bytes packets is 117.35 Mbp/s.
However I'm getting 957 Mbp/s for UDP traffic of 1514 packets. I generate the traffic 
with netperf.

I am not sure how this can be possible. Does netperf return udp/tcp or 
Ethernet throughput?

Comment: b = bit, B = Bytes

if you see it otherwise, it is wrong.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That image says that the maximum UDP transfer rate over 1gbps ethernet is 119635891 **Bytes** per second.

Multiple 119635891 with 8 (one byte is 8 bits) and you get 957087128 == 957,08mbps